# How do I run a function after the nth time opening the app or after n days?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I want to run a function/set a boolean after the user has opened the app for the nth time (n being any number I want).

Likewise I want to run a function/set a boolean after n days since first launch.

I was thinking about making a framework for this, but I am not sure where to start. Is there any existing frameworks/Cocoapods that do this? If not, can someone give me some hints/suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Every time your script is run, add a value to a file. Then, if the value gets big enough, run the function and reset the value. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you tu use `UserDefaults` to track how much times the user launched your app. 
There is a framework [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate/blob/master/iRate/iRate.m) that allows you to choose after how much app launch And / Or days to prompt user to rate your app. 
To keep track the number of days since installation & number of times the has been launched you can do something like that

// FUNCTION to call from appDelegate didFinishLaunching method

```
func trackUsage() {
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
 let installationDate = defaults.object(forKey: "installationDate") as? Date
 if installationDate == nil { // this is the first launch of the app
   defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "installationDate")
 }
 let usageCount = defaults.integer(forKey: "usageCount") ?? 0
 defaults.set(usageCount + 1, forKey: "usageCount")
 defaults.synchronize()
}
```

then before calling your function you can do :

```
if defaults.integer(forKey: "usageCount") ?? 0 > 10 {
    // the app has been launched at least 10 times
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! My initial thought was something like that. Nice to know I'm on the right track haha.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest was would be to utilize `UserDefaults`. Set it in the `viewDidLoad` of you main `ViewController`.

```
func setNumberOfStarts(){
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
//will return 0 if not set previously 
var numberOfStarts: Int = defaults.integer(forKey: "starts") 
numberOfStarts = numberOfStarts + 1

defaults.set(numberOfStarts, forKey: "starts")
}
```

Query it where you need it.

```
func getNumberOfStarts() -> Int{
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
//will return 0 if not set previously 
let numberOfStarts: Int = defaults.integer(forKey: "starts") 
return numberOfStarts
}
```

Do with the results as you need.

```
let MAXIMUM_STARTS: Int = 10
func startedEnough() -> Bool{
    var enough = false
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let numberOfStarts: Int = defaults.integer(forKey: "starts")
    if numberOfStarts > MAXIMUM_STARTS {
        enough = true
    }
    return enough
}
```

Comment: Sorry LastMove I was still typing and did see that you had already posted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try it!